# change folder permission from drwxr-sr-x to drwxrwsr-x

Tags: files, permissions, group, gid

I'm trying to change directory permission from `drwxr-sr-x`  to `drwxrwsr-x`.

I tried to run `chmod g+w`, but it turned to `drwxrwSr-x`.
The upper case s (S) did not work.

Could you give any help on this?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try `chmod 02775 dirname` to set the permissions. Symbolic permissions are nice but I still prefer setting explicit perms using octal.

Comment: I cant read the text in the image; please post text as text. And if I could, I would say that it is not inline with what you said: I see no `S`.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are doing. There is no reason that `g+w` should change `s` to `S`. Did you do something else that you aren't mentioning here? In my Centos 8 VM with BASH, using the same command that you did on a directory with the same permissions gives `drwxrwsr-x` which is what you want.

Comment: I'm really struggling to read those images. Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Remove this **S** permission as this is risky from security point to use it.

Here you will find how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626460/linux-ubuntu-9-04-permissions-how-do-i-remove-rws

Then try to change permission using **chmod g+w** once again.

Comment: But having perms `02775` is absolutely essential in some situations. Giving a blanket answer of "don't do this" without knowing why the OP wants/needs it really doesn't address his needs.

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't specify this, so maybe in this case, solution will work for him.

Comment: Since the OP said this is what he wanted, I'd give him the benefit of the doubt. Possibly tell OP how to do what he wants but also point out any downsides.

Comment: The `setgid` on a directory just makes it so that the files and directories created inside are owned by the specified group. In this case, it doesn't matter anyway because there is an uppercase S which means that the group doesn't have execute permissions on the directory so the permission is benign. That's strange in and of itself considering what he did but I'll address that with a comment to the question.